# Greyed out flag options

Tags: bug, flags, user-interface

Not sure if [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or not:

When reviewing an already-raised flag (in this case, Rude/Abusive), I found the option I had selected greyed out (as expected), but also the spam option greyed out as well. Is that supposed to be the case?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

"Spam" and "Rude/Abusive" flags are classified as high-priority, and get special treatment, i.e. they have a blinking marquee <sub><sub>not really</sub></sub> so mods pay attention to them ASAP.

Thus, when you raise either of the flags, you can't raise the other type on the same post, and when you retract one such flag on a post, you can't cast the other type on it either. (If you retract a spam flag on a post, you won't be able to flag it as rude/abusive, and vice versa)

The only disadvantage to this is sometimes mods decline spam flags on rude posts, but that has a good reason; it's because an abusive post, for instance gibberish, confuses the spam filters if deleted as spam.